# How to determine sql server security mode in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Does anyone know how to determine the security mode (Mixed Mode or Windows Authentication) in .NET?

**EDIT**:  I am using normal ADO.NET objects (SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc) to connect to the database.

Thanks for any and all advice.

Steve

Comment: Need more info?  How are you interacting with SS?

Comment: Test with a valid SQL Server login for the instance - if it fails, only other option is Windows Auth.

Comment: I am not sure if SMO (Shared Management Objects) can help in this or not but give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the registry!

```
DECLARE @LoginMode int
EXEC master..xp_regread 
     @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
     @key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer\', 
     @value_name = 'LoginMode',
     @value = @LoginMode output
PRINT @LoginMode
```

1 = SQL
2 = Mixed

The `@key` may be different depending on your installation. I have a couple instances running.

Comment: This is excellent!  Thanks Dustin, that's exactly what I was looking for!